# Handsontable in bootstrap Model popover cannot load All column, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Handsontable jquery plugin for a project where user click button and a popover come and input data on the table. I use bootstrap model for popover.

**Here is my html**

```
<li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <i class="fa fa-table"></i>
</li>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content ">
      <div class="modal-header text-left">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Hotlist</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">  

       <div id="hotlist"></div>

        <div class="upload-form-hotlist">
            <form action="">
                <input type="file">
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handsontable

    $("#hotlist").handsontable({
        startRows: 5,
        startCols: 5,
        minRows: 5,
        minCols: 5,
        maxRows: 100,
        maxCols: 100,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        contextMenu: true
    });

    // This way, you can access Handsontable api methods by passing their names as an argument, e.g.:
    var hotInstance = $("#hotlist").handsontable('getInstance');

});
```

Now what happen snapshot

[image: Now what happen snapshot]

but i click any where in the table i get what i want but why need to click on the table . please help me out .

What i expected picture

[image: What i expected picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try and found an answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Handsontable

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

    $("#hotlist").handsontable({
        startRows: 5,
        startCols: 5,
        minRows: 5,
        minCols: 5,
        maxRows: 100,
        maxCols: 100,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        contextMenu: true
    });

    // This way, you can access Handsontable api methods by passing their names as an argument, e.g.:
    var hotInstance = $("#hotlist").handsontable('getInstance');
});

});
```